# pycharm - keep focus in editor when sending commands to python console

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, rstudio

Same question as

[Sypder 2 IDE - keep the focus in the editor after sending selected commands to interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561122/sypder-2-ide-keep-the-focus-in-the-editor-after-sending-selected-commands-to-i)

but for JetBrains PyCharm. Using option-shift-e on a mac, I can send commands to the python console, but I have to press esc to return focus to the editor. Can I do the Rstudio-style / Emacs-ESS style execution where focus stays in the editor window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using PyCharm 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Netbeans keymap.

I can use `CTRL+ALT+E` to execute selected command and for the first time the console has a focus, indeed (first time after lauching IDE). However, any further `CTRL+ALT+E` leaves the focus on editor. (I can switch back to the console, which is named `Run`, using `ALT+4`.)

If newer versions of PyCharm are behaving differently then maybe it's a bug.

[image]

Comment: downloaded the newest version and the bahvior makes sense. Must have been in a bug in the EAP build I was using.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in console and/or built in terminal.